# Does "be remembered for" have another meaning that is similar to "worth remembering"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/a7tfyzeZJCc?t=203)

> in the
>   following exercise I'm either going to
>   show you some data, or describe a concept
>   to you and you're going to have to
>   select a function which you think might
>   be used to represent it.
>
> this is not
>   intended to be a difficult exercise but
>   what I would like you to understand is
>   that selecting a function is the
>   creative essence of science.
>
> this process
>   of selecting a candidate function or
>   hypothesis to model a world is what the
>   great geniuses of science are remembered for.

Cambridge gives this [explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remember?q=be%20remembered%20for)

> to be kept in people's memories because of a particular action or quality:

and this example

> She will be remembered for her courage.

Which seems to be different to the meaning the lecturer meant.

Comment: Why do you think the two examples are "different"? The great geniuses of science came up with good ways to model the world, which is why we still talk and write about who they were and what they did. She was courageous, which is why people do the same for her *because of her courage*. So far as I'm concerned, both contexts match your cited definition perfectly well.

Comment: Neither of the definitions you've provided has the meaning *worth remembering*. You seem to have used that different interpretation without any supporting evidence. (It means something quite different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the definition you have found online and I do think that is what your lecturer meant.

Lets simplify the sentence a little by removing "excess" information:

> This process is what the great geniuses of science are remembered for.

By this, the lecturer means that "the great geniuses of science" (such as Newton or Einstein) are "kept in people's memories because of" *this process*.

I.e. He is saying that the "process of selecting a candidate function or hypothesis to model a world" is really important. His evidence for that is that "the great geniuses of science" are remembered for it.

Comment: The meaning of the lecturer could be rewritten as "the great geniuses of science, such as Newton, Einstein are remembered for **this process**", right?

Comment: yes, I would interpret that way. Native BrE

Comment: May this is better, "the great geniuses of science, such as Newton, Einstein are remembered for **using this process**"

Comment: That also works, but is just a bit more lengthy

Answer (score -1):

Both examples have the same meaning.

Great scientists are *remembered for* their ability to select good models.

In your second example, she is *remembered for* her courage.

The answer to your question is yes.

Someone being "remembered for" something means that they have done something worth remembering.

**Some examples:**

> Martin Luther King Jr. *is remembered* for his civil rights work.
>
> Albert Einstein *is remembered* for his theory of relativity.
>
> Richard Bellman and Lester Ford *are remembered* for their work in algorithms.